# Using the make command without makefiles?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, makefile

I was compiling some C code for an assignment and I ran "make codeFile", where "codeFile" was the name of my C program, and even though I didn't have a makefile, an executable was created, and it ran and worked correctly.

Does anyone know why this worked? Why does make compile something even if I don't have a makefile? The only reference I could find was this: 
http://daly.axiom-developer.org/TimothyDaly_files/class5/node5.html

Answer (score 14):

Make has an internal database with implicit rules. You can use `make -p` to list them. Also `make -d` will tell you which rules are being applied, so that would help you discover which implicit rules are being used in this case.

Answer (score 12):

Make has several pre-defined [*implicit rules*](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Implicit-Rules).  In particular, in your case, it uses two such rules when trying to determine what to do for the target `codeFile`:

```
%: %.o    # Link object file
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)

%.o: %.c  # Compile C source code
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c
```

Answer (score 7):

> **Using the make command without makefiles?**

`make` has implicit rules that work as defaults unless you override them.

According to the [make man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/make):

```
make -p -f/dev/null
```

will list all of the implicit rules (and relevant environment variables) without attempting to actually remake files.

To demonstrate the usage, I ran `make` in Cygwin, which gave me an `exe` file. Note no `.c` on the name passed to make:

```
$ ls
hello.c
$ make hello
cc     hello.c   -o hello
$ ls
hello.c  hello.exe
```

I also ran this in Ubuntu Linux, and my result was nearly the same as above, but the `.exe` extension was not there, instead I had the plain `hello` executable:

```
$ ls
hello.c  hello
```

**Step by step derivation**

I believe the relevant pieces of the make implicit rules are as follows:

```
CC = cc
```

`cc` is aliased to `CC`

```
LINK.c = $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

a `LINK` format is created, where the flags will be empty, and the `TARGET_ARCH` variable is also empty ([to allow users to set values for various target architectures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18476490/what-is-purpose-of-target-arch-variable-in-makefiles).) Then we have:

```
%: %.c
#  recipe to execute (built-in):
        $(LINK.c) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

The `^` variable is the prerequisite, `hello.c`. The other variables are empty. These are followed by the `-o` flag and the target name. The empty variables explain the extra spaces in the command make ran:

```
cc     hello.c   -o hello
```

And the `%: %.c` matched the target given to make with the filename of the same target name ending in `.c`, which caused the recipe to execute.