# What is purpose of TARGET_ARCH variable in Makefiles

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have noticed that in Implicit Rules in Gnu Make is variable $(TARGET_ARCH) for example :

```
$(LINK.o) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
LINK.o = $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH)
```

I supposed that this variable is needed for cross compilation, but I haven't found any information about it in Gnu Make documentation.

Comment: How is that variable set?

Answer (score 3):

I agree that it's probably meant for cross-compilation. 
The variable TARGET_ARCH has no default value - it's there for end-users to define as they see fit.