# make - specify library to link from the command line (without Makefile)

Tags: c, makefile

For simple program eg, `proc.c` which has only one source file, it's convenient to compile and link using just `make proc`, which by default search for `proc.c` and create `proc` as output file. There is no need to create a `Makefile` for that.

If `proc.c` requires to link with some library such as the math library (defined by `<math.h>`). Using `gcc` directly, we can use `gcc -c proc.c -o proc -lm`. Is there an equivalent `make` command line option to specify `-lm` so we can use `make` command directly without writing a `Makefile`?

---

Similar task suggested by Basile Starynkevitch:

[Makefile with Multiple Executables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16751611/a-makefile-with-multiple-executables/16751650#16751650)

Comment: I believe you should write a *simple* `Makefile` like [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16751650/841108)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### **Link library with make without makefile**

If your source file is prova.c then you can do the following:

```
$> export LDFLAGS=-lm; make prova
```

or:

```
$> export LDLIBS=-lm; make prova    # LDLIBS works on Linux (but LDFLAGS doesn't)
```

or:

```
$ make prova LDLIBS=-lm
```

as Make uses this implicit rule:

```
%: %.o    # Link object file
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

Make has several implicit rules, you can see all of them with make -p.
For further information see this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745241/using-the-make-command-without-makefiles).

Comment: thanks, but does this actually work? I tried a `fmod` function in `proc.c` and using your command it still reported `undefined reference to `fmod'`

Comment: perhaps `make prova LIBES=-lm`

Comment: Tried again on a linux box (I was on OS X), worked with the above but not with gcc prova.c. As suggested by @Basile, try also LIBS.

Comment: ok I'm on Linux (Ubuntu) and `LDLIBS=-lm` works (the first `LDFLAGS` doesn't)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch - yes it works with `make prova LDLIBS=-lm`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I guess Basile means LIBES not LIBS as LOADLIBES is also added in the linker line. And in fact for me works if you set LOADLIBES=-lm