# Why does makefile automatically generate object file(*.o) without any specific rule?

Tags: c, makefile

I am learning to write makefile recently. All the documents I am reading tell me that I have to write a rule to execute commands.
But I found that the following Makefile could generate object files with out any compile command. Why?

```
SOURCES=$(wildcard  src/*.c)
OBJECTS=$(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SOURCES))

all: $(OBJECTS)
```

When I type make in terminal, I get this:

```
cc -c -o xxx.o xxx.c
```

How does it happened?

Comment: Read on until you reach the chapter about built-in rules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Why does makefile automatically generate object file(*.o) without any
>   specific rule?

**Because it has a set of Built-in rules.**

---

Make uses implicit rules like the following:

```
%.o: %.c  
    $(CC) $(CPPFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) -c

%: %.o    
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) n.o $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS)
```

You can see all of them with `make -p`. While `make -d`shows the applied rules.

As Ian Abbott pointed out in the comment:

> `make -p` needs to be run from a directory that has no makefile (and
>   no Makefile, and no GNUmakefile).

See also the relevant GNU make [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Catalogue-of-Rules)

and this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745241/using-the-make-command-without-makefiles).

Comment: To avoid confusion, the `make -p` needs to be run from a directory that has no makefile (and no Makefile, and no GNUmakefile).

Comment: Thanks for clarification, I'll add it

Comment: Even in a directory with a makefile you can see which rules are built-in (it is in the `-p` output) but you might miss some built-in rules if the makefile overrides them.