# I'm starting coding and am stuck on hello world

Tags: c, cs50

I'm new to coding and doing the first CS50 course exercise where we are taught to code using C and doing the "hello world" activity. I input the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    printf("hello, world\n");
```

and when I type in the terminal `make hello` and `./hello` it says `hello is a directory` instead of doing the command.

What should I do?

Comment: I take it that you are using UNIX of some kind. Do you know how to use `ls` and `cat`? Can you verify that you put that code into a file? What is the exact name of the file?

Comment: the error is obvious, you already have a folder named `hello` in the current directory, just remove it

Comment: ... after checking to make sure there's nothing in there you want to keep.

Comment: @drescherjm No, `make` has implicit rules and can work without Makefile.

Comment: @dimich Thanks for the correction. I learned something today..: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745241/using-the-make-command-without-makefiles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15745241/using-the-make-command-without-makefiles)

Comment: Please add directory contents (`ls -l` or `ls -alR` if that is not too long) and output of `make hello`. As a guess, you were going to use directory `hello`, and created it, but forgot to change to that directiry, so now you have `hello.c` and `hello` subdirectory in same directory.

Comment: So, solution you want is probably, `cd hello` then `mv ../hello.c .` then `make hello` then `./hello`. It is _imporrtant_ to read and try to understand the output of these commands. I have hard time believing `make` didn't already give you an error...

Answer (score 2):

C is a compiled language, so once you compile the code, it will output an executable that unless specified by `-o [executable-name]`, will be called `a.out`. Your hello world program should look like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    printf("hello, world\n");
}
```

Don't forget the closing bracket at the end. To compile this code, make sure you have GCC installed and run `gcc [program-file-name].c`, and replace the second argument with the name of the C file. Once the code is compiled, you can see that a file named `a.out` has appeared in your current directory. You can then run `./a.out` to run the program.

I'm assuming your system comes with GCC, but if it doesn't, there are many resources on Google to help, including https://gcc.gnu.org/install/.

Comment: But good job on a nicely formatted answer and being willing to help.

Comment: Reworded, but added. Thanks!

Comment: I think OP is using implicit GNU make rules, in which case this answer is going to be very confusing...

Comment: `int main(void)`, (OP did it properly.)